# Keyless entity model in Entity Framework (6.1.3)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Is there any way to make an entity keyless? It is possible on newer version of Entity Framework Core with attribute [Keyless] , but I needed it to work on older versions. Is there any way we can update it through fluent api?

Answer (score 1):

No.  But if you don't update the entity, you can declare the entity key to be whatever you want.

Comment: tried that with composite keys, in one table had to add composite key to all fields, but yet there were duplicates (I'm bulk importing from csv file from external data source)

Comment: Sounds like a poor fit for EF.  Instead use ADO.NET directly.